# Shell script with loop, camera and fbi

Tags: camera, fbi, fswebcam

I want to write a shell script which regularly / continuously captures images from a webcamera (via fswebcam) e.g. every second and show it then on the screen using fbi. In this way I want to have a ind of live imaging. (I found no linux tool for regular live imaging)
But I am stuck with the syntax, so far found no good tutorial in the internet for this. Any hints how to proceed?

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: Please give us the syntax you are stuck.